# Transfer mySQL from development to production

Tags: mysql, dev-to-production

I need to synch development mysql db with the production one. 
Production db gets updated by user clicks and other data generated via web.
Development db gets updated with processing data.

What's the best practice to accomplish this?

I found some diff tools (eg. mySQL diff), but they don't manage updated records.
I also found some application solution: http://www.isocra.com/2004/10/dumptosql/ 
but I'm not sure it's a good practice as in this case I need to retest my code each time I add  new innodb related tables.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you need this for one time or you need to do this regularly?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/90301/sync-two-mysql-databases i think this might be helpful

Comment: Thanks, I've taken a look at them, one is master/slave to exactly copy the db (but I can't because on production I have user generated data I don't have in development). The other solution is been discussed in the next answer, I just need to understand if it manages the updated records too.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `mysqldump`. It may serve you well enough for this.

Assuming your tables are all indexed with some sort of unique key you could do a dump and have it leave out the 'drop/create table' bits. Have it run as 'insert ignore' and you'll get the new data without effecting the existing data.

Another option would be to use the query part of mysqldump to dump only the new records from the production side. Again - have mysqldump leave off the 'drop/create' bits.

Comment: Thanks, how do I managed updated records? I guess here records have already been indexed.

Comment: For scenario #2 you'll need some way to identify them. For #1 you dump everything and let the unique keys sort them out. It's a bit harsh but it does work.